# WPF: How can I remove the searchbox in a DocumentViewer?

Tags: wpf, documentviewer

My XAML code is like this:

```
<Window
    xmlns                 ='http://schemas.microsoft.com/netfx/2007/xaml/presentation'
    xmlns:x               ='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'
    Title                 ='Print Preview - More stuff here'
    Height                ='200'
    Width                 ='300'
    WindowStartupLocation ='CenterOwner'>
    <DocumentViewer Name='dv1' ... />
</Window>
```

How can I, in XAML or in C#, eliminate the search box?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Vlad's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322727/wpf-how-can-i-remove-the-searchbox-in-a-documentviewer/2322743#2322743) led me to look at how to programmatically grab the ContentControl that holds the find toolbar.  I didn't really want to write an entirely new template for the DocumentViewer; I wanted to change (hide) only one control.  That reduced the problem to *how to retrieve a control that is applied via a template?*.
Here's what I figured out:

```
  Window window = ... ; 
  DocumentViewer dv1 = LogicalTreeHelper.FindLogicalNode(window, "dv1") as DocumentViewer;
  ContentControl cc = dv1.Template.FindName("PART_FindToolBarHost", dv1) as ContentControl;
  cc.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Comment: +1. But: in order to make this working without the "findLogicalNode" and before the window is displayed, it needs the code of  [Quarkonium response](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9270218/218873) first : `dv1.ApplyTemplate();`

Answer (score 20):

You can do something similar to [Cheeso's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2323275/203816) with a style for `ContentControl` and a trigger to hide it when the name is `PART_FindToolBarHost`.

```
<DocumentViewer>
  <DocumentViewer.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Name" Value="PART_FindToolBarHost">
          <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </DocumentViewer.Resources>
</DocumentViewer>
```

Answer (score 6):

As Vlad pointed out you can replace the control template. Unfortunately, the control template available on MSDN is not the real control template used by the `DocumentViewer` control. Here is the correct template modified to hide the search bar by setting `Visibility="Collapsed"` on `PART_FindToolBarHost`:

```
<!-- DocumentViewer style with hidden search bar. -->
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}" xmlns:Documents="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Documents;assembly=PresentationUI">
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowTextBrushKey}}"/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
  <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerContextMenu, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DocumentViewer}">
        <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Focusable="False">
          <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Local">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
              <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <ContentControl Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource {ComponentResourceKey ResourceId=PUIDocumentViewerToolBarStyleKey, TypeInTargetAssembly={x:Type Documents:PresentationUIStyleResources}}}" TabIndex="0"/>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" CanContentScroll="true" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" IsTabStop="true" Grid.Row="1" TabIndex="1"/>
            <DockPanel Grid.Row="1">
              <FrameworkElement DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.VerticalScrollBarWidthKey}}"/>
              <Rectangle Height="10" Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="top">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                  <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                      <GradientStopCollection>
                        <GradientStop Color="#66000000" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="1"/>
                      </GradientStopCollection>
                    </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                  </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
              </Rectangle>
            </DockPanel>
            <ContentControl x:Name="PART_FindToolBarHost" Grid.Column="0" Focusable="{TemplateBinding Focusable}" Grid.Row="2" TabIndex="2" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
          </Grid>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

You need to add a reference to `PresentationUI.dll`. This assembly is located in the folder `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\WPF`.

Answer (score 4):

You can replace a control template for it. For your reference: the default `DocumentViewer`'s control template is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970452.aspx

The search toolbar's name is `PART_FindToolBarHost`, so you can also just assign its `Visibility` to `Collapsed`.

---

Edit:
As the comment from @Martin suggests, the control template in MSDN (referenced above) is not fully correct. A better way to extract a template which is actually used in WPF by default would be using Blend (Edit Control Template in the context menu, if I am not mistaken).

Comment: This is the 'right' solution except there is a bug where you will get the design mode (not run time) exception `'Zoom' is not a valid value for property 'Command'.`. See http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/566538/document-viewer-controltemplate for more information.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get Cheeso's answer to work in the constructor I had to add:

```
dv1.ApplyTemplate();
```

otherwise cc comes out null. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2286693/1196481)

Answer (score 2):

```
 <DocumentViewer>
     <DocumentViewer.Resources>
         <!-- Toolbar -->          
         <Style TargetType="ToolBar">
             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
         </Style>
          <!-- Search -->
         <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
             <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
         </Style>
     </DocumentViewer.Resources>
</DocumentViewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you need a **DocumentViewer**? You could use a **FlowDocumentScrollViewer** instead, or if you like pagination or multi-column display, you could use a **FlowDocumentPageViewer**.

Comment: I want a DocumentViewer because my goal is to produce print preview, and the XpsDocument is the thing that paginates visuals automatically.  I could do this with a FDSV and some other custom code, but... I'd rather do the lazy thing.

Comment: you got me wondering how you do print preview for FlowDocuments...fwiw, from "Pro WPF in C# 2008" looks like you write the flow doc out as an XPS file then read it back in (as a fixed document) and finally display it in a DocumentViewer...wow!