# Binding with ElementName not working for dynamic constructed control inside WPF TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a checkbox and a comboBox, both constructed at code behind as follows:

```
 var el = new ComboBox();
 var checkBox = new CheckBox { Name = "myCheckBox" };
 el.SetBinding(UIEelement.IsEnabledProperty, new Binding("IsChecked") { ElementName = checkBox.Name });
```

They are both placed inside the same Grid.

The binding works fine if I place the Grid directly inside my UserControl.
But, when I place the Grid inside a TabItem, then put the TabItem inside a TabControl at my UserControl, the binding doesn't work.

We were able to fix this by changin the binding as follows, but I really want to understand why the previous does not work.

```
 el.SetBinding(UIEelement.IsEnabledProperty, new Binding("IsChecked") { Source = checkBox });
```

Is it a problem of scope, even if the checkbox and the combo are in the same one?

Comment: Can you post your Xaml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Arie's answer I was able to understand the problem.

Apparently my TabItem didn't have a NameScope (`NameScope.GetNameScope(tabItem)` returns null). So I've set the TabItem namescope as myUserControl namescope:

```
  NameScope.SetNameScope(tabItem, NameScope.GetNameScope(myUserControl));
```

Answer (score 3):

It's probably an issue concerning [namescopes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659(v=vs.110).aspx). `TabItem` is a container and has its own namescope, inwhich you'll have to register the name of the control that you created in codebehind, using `myNameScope.RegisterName()`, e.g like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22917798/891715). Then you'll be able to bind using `ElementName`.